# Delete all elements of an array, that has the delete: true property

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

everybody.
I have an array of map objects. Its like this;

```
[
    {
        "link": "./1.css",
        "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1.css",
        "css": "css only gets text",
        "parentCSS": -1,
        "childCSSs": [
            {
                "link": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                "url": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                "css": "css only gets text",
                "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1.css",
                "childCSSs": [],
                "delete": false
            },
            {
                "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
                "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
                "css": "css only gets text",
                "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1.css",
                "childCSSs": [
                    {
                        "link": "https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css",
                        "url": "https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css",
                        "css": "css only gets text",
                        "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
                        "childCSSs": [],
                        "delete": false
                    },
                    {
                        "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
                        "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
                        "css": "css only gets text",
                        "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
                        "childCSSs": [
                            {
                                "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
                                "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
                                "css": "css only gets text",
                                "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
                                "childCSSs": [],
                                "delete": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "delete": false
                    }
                ],
                "delete": false
            }
        ],
        "delete": false
    },
    {
        "link": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "url": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "css": "css only gets text",
        "parentCSS": -1,
        "childCSSs": [],
        "delete": true
    },
    {
        "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
        "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
        "css": "css only gets text",
        "parentCSS": -1,
        "childCSSs": [
            {
                "link": "https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css",
              "url":"https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css",
                "css": "css only gets text",
                "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
                "childCSSs": [],
                "delete": false
            },
            {
                "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
                "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
                "css": "css only gets text",
                "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css",
                "childCSSs": [
                    {
                        "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
                        "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
                        "css": "css only gets text",
                        "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
                        "childCSSs": [],
                        "delete": false
                    }
                ],
                "delete": false
            }
        ],
        "delete": true
    },
    {
        "link": "https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css",
        "url": "https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css",
        "css": "css only gets text",
        "parentCSS": -1,
        "childCSSs": [],
        "delete": true
    },
    {
        "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
        "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
        "css": "css only gets text",
        "parentCSS": -1,
        "childCSSs": [
            {
                "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
                "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
                "css": "css only gets text",
                "parentCSS": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css",
                "childCSSs": [],
                "delete": false
            }
        ],
        "delete": true
    },
    {
        "link": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
        "url": "http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css",
        "css": "css only gets text",
        "parentCSS": -1,
        "childCSSs": [],
        "delete": true
    }
]
```

I want to delete all elements that have `delete: true` with their `childCSS: [...]` array's objects. How can i do that? I tried to do this;

```
links.forEach((link, index) => {
    postTraverse(link, links, index);
});

const postTraverse = (obj, links, index) => {
    if(!obj.delete) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty('childCSSs')) {
            if(obj.childCSSs.length > 0) {
                obj.childCSSs.forEach((childObj, childIndex) => {
                    return postTraverse(childObj, links, childIndex);
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty('childCSSs')) {
            if(obj.parentCSS == -1) {
                links.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                obj.childCSSs.splice(index, 1);
            }
        } else {
            links.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

This method for solve problem, skips some elements cause of after `array.splice(index, 1)`, so the array's length decreases 1 and index for `array.forEach((link, index) => {...})` this statement does not decreases. The problem is here but if there any better way to solve this problem, it can be very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `.filter` that filters an item's `childCSSs` properties too, if the item is to be kept in the array:

```js
const doFilter = arr => arr.filter((item) => {
  if (item.delete) return false;
  item.childCSSs = doFilter(item.childCSSs);
  return true;
});

const input=[{"link":"./1.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":-1,"childCSSs":[{"link":"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css","url":"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1.css","childCSSs":[],"delete":!1},{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1.css","childCSSs":[{"link":"https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css","url":"https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","childCSSs":[],"delete":!1},{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","childCSSs":[{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","childCSSs":[],"delete":!1}],"delete":!1}],"delete":!1}],"delete":!1},{"link":"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css","url":"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":-1,"childCSSs":[],"delete":!0},{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":-1,"childCSSs":[{"link":"https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css","url":"https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","childCSSs":[],"delete":!1},{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2.css","childCSSs":[{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","childCSSs":[],"delete":!1}],"delete":!1}],"delete":!0},{"link":"https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css","url":"https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":-1,"childCSSs":[],"delete":!0},{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":-1,"childCSSs":[{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2.css","childCSSs":[],"delete":!1}],"delete":!0},{"link":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","url":"http://opdetect.com/x/1-2-2-1.css","css":"css only gets text","parentCSS":-1,"childCSSs":[],"delete":!0}]

console.log(doFilter(input));
```

Comment: Man! Are you a joke?? This work well! Thanks so much, I did work 2 days for this problem but you made it with 5 lines of code :) Have good life!